# VBA if column B is not empty and not #NA return value in column D

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add text to column D if column B in the same row is not empty and not giving #NA values.

This is my current code for not empty but i have no idea how to make it IF for both criteria

```
    Dim NoPK As Range
    Set NoPK = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Existing").Range("D2:D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    
    For Each p In NoPK
        If p > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Existing").Range("M2:M" & Rows.Count).Value = "PK"
        End If
    Next p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Range("D2:D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` doesn't locate the last data cell on col D. Please see the below code.
- Use `And` / `Or` in `If` clause for multiple conditions

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [IsEmpty function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008952)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim NoPK As Range, p As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Existing")
        Set NoPK = .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
        ' OR
'        Set NoPK = .Range("D2:D" & .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each p In NoPK
            If Not (p.Text = "#N/A" Or IsEmpty(p.Value)) Then
                .Cells(p.Row, "M").Value = "PK"
            End If
        Next p
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can proceed as follows:

```
Dim NoPK As Range
Dim existingSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set existingSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Existing")
lastRow = existingSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(existingSheet.Range("B" & i).Value) And existingSheet.Range("B" & i).Value <> "#NA" Then
        existingSheet.Range("D" & i).Value = "Your Text Here"
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Specialcells()` method of `Range` object and avoid looping

and a conscious use of `On Error Resume Next` would let you get rid of many `If-Then` checks

```
Sub PK()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Existing")
        With .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            On Error Resume Next
            Union(.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks), _
                  .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors), _
                  .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                  
            .Offset(, 9).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "PK"
            .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```